# How to keep track of the ID relationships when using an SQL Server MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using a MERGE statement to "push" products from our POS to our website. However, I need to be able to keep track of the IDs in both the source and target tables being used by my MERGE statement... Basically, I want to generate a table that keeps track of tblA ID <> tblB ID relationships. It's easier just to show you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc8b40/3/0

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to record the source.ID in the tblMappings table (I tried simply `source.ID`, but that didn't work). Anyone know how I could do this?

One requirement: the query needs to be able to run via the PHP SQLSRV driver.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Source.ID` should actually work. What do you see when you use `Source.ID` instead of `DELETED.ID`?

Comment: should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da944/1

Comment: Ha! It works... Maybe I made a typo when I tried it... Thanks for verifying!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had the right idea with `source.ID`, but evidently I had a typo somewhere when I tried it- because it works just fine now! Thanks @cha

```
MERGE tblTarget AS target
USING (
  SELECT
    ID,
    SKU,
    Name
  FROM tblSource
) AS source (
  ID,
  SKU,
  Name
)
ON (target.SKU = source.SKU)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
      Name = source.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (
    SKU,
    Name
  )
  VALUES (
    source.SKU,
    source.Name
  )
OUTPUT
  $ACTION ChangeType,
  COALESCE(Inserted.SKU, Deleted.SKU) SKU,
  /* The source table's alias works just fine apparently... */
  source.ID SRC_ID,
  Inserted.ID TGT_ID,
  GETUTCDATE() Last_Updated
INTO tblMappings;

SELECT *
FROM tblMappings;
```